# Necesito activar ctrl+p para guardar una página web como PDF

Tags: excel, web, vba

Tengo una código en visual basic, con este ingreso a una página de búsqueda pero necesito guardar la página completa como PDF, y hacer esto con todos los datos de la columna A.

Este es mi código

```
'Option Explicit

Sub ExtraerDatos()

Dim IE As Object

Dim c As Long, UltimaFila As Long

Dim Celda As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Let UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

IE.navigate "http://192.168.1.76/frmPrincipal.aspx"

IE.Visible = True

For Each Celda In Range("A2:A" & UltimaFila)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

With IE

.Document.getElementById("txtDato").Value = Celda.Value

.Document.getElementById("btnCon").Click

**Aqui necesito que guarde la pagina web**

Do Until IE.readyState = 4

DoEvents

Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

End With

Next Celda

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Proceso finalizado"

End Sub'
```

---

avance hasta aquí mi código, he conseguido que se abra la ventana para escribir el nombre, pero no puedo hacer que el nombre del archivo sea el mismo de la celda ni tampoco darle clic en guardar.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtraerDatos()

Dim IE As Object
Dim c As Long, UltimaFila As Long
Dim elementsTable As Object, elementsTableDiv As Object
Dim Celda As Range
Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
Const PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Let UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

IE.navigate "http://192.168.1.76/frmPrincipal.aspx"
IE.Visible = True

For Each Celda In Range("A2:A" & UltimaFila)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

With IE
.Document.getElementById("txtDato").Value = Celda.Value
.Document.getElementById("btnCon").Click
.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER

End With

Next Celda

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Proceso finalizado"

End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Y qué has intentado para guardarlo en PDF?

Comment: Hola para imprimir en PDF, seleccione como predeterminado que al darle control+p  se seleccione esta opción, avance mi código, te lo dejo en la respuesta, lo que no consigo es que el nombre del archivo sea el mismo que el de la celda usada, ni tampoco consigo darle clic en Guardar en el cuadro de dialogo.

Comment: Amigo, has intentado usar AUTOIT, es una maravilla para automatizar IE y es estable, es una pena que en stackoverflow no tenga su etiqueta, es solo una sugerencia